# What can i actually do if my wordpress dashboard is acting up? other admins of my site dont have these problems

Tags: wordpress

-In the past i could hover over any item in the dashboard i.e. settings and its inner elements would show such as general, reading, writing.

Now i need to click on settings > page navigates to settings > now i can see the elements

-In plugins i cant navigate to other tabs, whenever i click on the tabs nothing happens. Feels broken.

-when i go to appearance > editor all my php and css files and such are expanded and there is no way to collapse as clicking on the arrows does nothing. I have to scroll the whole time to find a file.

-whenever i check page revisions it shows a blank page.

Other admins of my website dont have any of these problems i listed!

Has anyone had this before? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned others aren't having the same problem.  That would indicate it has to do with something on your side of things.

1. Try another web browser.
2. Try another computer.
3. What is your network speed?  You can do a speed test.

Comment: Other browser did the trick.
On my old laptop i've always used chrome though and even temporarily on my new laptop.

Quite annoying that this has happened.

Thanks though!